# How to make TranslateAnimation smooth?

Tags: android, android-animation

There's a scanner line in the CaptureActivity. Now I want to add a TranslateAnimation and let the line move from the top of the "hot area" to the bottom, but it's not smooth at all. I don't know why?

Here's a code snippet

```
FrameLayout.LayoutParams linearParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
linearParams.width = width;
mImageView.setLayoutParams(linearParams);
mImageView.invalidate();
mImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

mTranslateAnimation.setDuration(3000);
mTranslateAnimation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
mImageView.startAnimation(mTranslateAnimation);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Image too large, device too slow, ...

Comment: @Henry it's a small image and device is not slow. (Quad-core 1.3 GHz)

Comment: can you add in the snippet where you define mTranslateAnimation?

Comment: @Whitney I think the root cause is that zxing is auto focusing. When it finishes scaning QR code, then animation is smooth enough.